# Why does autowired and resource produce different key for maps?

Tags: spring

i have a class which has:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Response> violationResponseMap;
```

where this is declared in the app context as:

```
<util:map id="violationResponseMap">
  <entry key="INVALID_PARAM" value-ref="X" />
</util:map>

<bean
 id="X"
 class="foo.bar.ViolationResponseFactoryBean"
 c:message="#{null}"
 c:status="404" />
```

when checking for the KeySet of violationResponseMap, i get:

```
X
```

however given the same bean declaration as above, when i change the annotation in the violationResponseMap as:

```
@Resource(name = "violationResponseMap")
private Map<String, Response> violationResponseMap;
```

i get the key `INVALID_PARAM`

Why does it produce different results when the declaration is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all explained in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

> (...) typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names

and

> (...) beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

Comment: Thanks for the links. For the second paragraph, i think the map is still injectected. It's just that the key values used are the bean IDs  instead of the declared entry key. Again Thank you

Comment: @geneqew Not **the** map, **a** map created by Spring. The `violationResponseMap` bean is not used and might as well not exist with `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

`@Resource` will wire the bean named `violationResponseMap` whereas `@Autowired` will inject a `Map` containing all the beans of type `Response` where the key is the name of the bean. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation.